# How to print a trenary tree in BFS?

Tags: c

i have a trenary tree:

```
typedef struct Trin_Ari {
int id;
char* name;
struct Trin_Ari *parent;
struct Trin_Ari *left;
struct Trin_Ari *middle;
struct Trin_Ari *right;
}Trin_Ari;
```

i got memebers in this order:
[image]

and i need to print them this way:

```
A1
B2
D4
G7
C3
E5
F6
H8
I9
```

Comment: Note: Drawing lacks nodes `G, H, I`.

Comment: You ask specifically about ternary trees. Do you know about doing it in binary trees? What is the the obstacle you encounter when trying to. I ask because your question does not demonstrate any own effort and seems to just ask for code. It also is unclear about the level of detail you need, from scratch it seems because of not demonstrating anything, but the title clearly focuses on ternary trees....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Level Order Tree Traversal.**

- start with the root node
- for each node

  - print node data
  - push children (if any) to the queue (enqueue - from left to right)
  - take the next element from the queue (dequeue)

**Code Example:**

```
// for test purpose
#define MAX_NODES 32

static struct {
    int head, tail;
    Trin_Ari* data[MAX_NODES]; // or allocate at runtime
} queue;

static void reset_queue()
{
    queue.head = queue.tail = 0;
    memset(queue.data, 0, sizeof(Trin_Ari*) * MAX_NODES);
}

static void enqueue(Trin_Ari *node)
{
    queue.data[queue.tail++] = node;
}

static Trin_Ari* dequeue()
{
    return queue.data[queue.head++];
}

void print(Trin_Ari *root)
{
    Trin_Ari *node = root;
    reset_queue();
    
    while (node) {

        // print node data
        printf("%i, %s\n", node->id, node->name);

        // enqueue child nodes
        if (node->left)   enqueue(node->left);
        if (node->middle) enqueue(node->middle);
        if (node->right)  enqueue(node->right);
        
        // dequeue a node from the queue
        node = dequeue();
        
    }
}
```

For the tree:

```
            A
    /       |       \
   B        C        D
 / | \    / | \    / | \
E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
```

**1. Iteration**

- print: A
- queue: B C D //enqueued
- node: B //dequeued

**2. Iteration**

- print: B
- queue: B C D E F G
- node: C

**3. Iteration**

- print: C
- queue: B C D E F G H I J
- node: D

**4. Iteration**

- print: D
- queue: B C D E F G H I J K L M
- node: E

**5. Iteration**

- print: E
- queue: B C D E F G H I J K L M //<- unchanged since E..M are leafs (no children)
- node: F

Iteration will continue until node M (last element in the queue).